# What is the proper way to use descriptors as fields in Python dataclasses?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-descriptors

I've been playing around with python dataclasses and was wondering: What is the most elegant or most pythonic way to make one or some of the fields descriptors?

In the example below I define a Vector2D class that should be compared on its length.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from math import sqrt

@dataclass(order=True)
class Vector2D:
    x: int = field(compare=False)
    y: int = field(compare=False)
    length: int = field(init=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        type(self).length = property(lambda s: sqrt(s.x**2+s.y**2))

Vector2D(3,4) > Vector2D(4,1) # True
```

While this code works, it touches the class every time an instance is created, is there a *more readable / less hacky / more intended* way to use dataclasses and descriptors together?

Just having *length* as a property and not a field will work but this means I have to write *`__lt__`, et.al.* by myself.

Another solution I found is equally unappealing:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Vector2D:
    x: int = field(compare=False)
    y: int = field(compare=False)
    length: int = field(init=False)
    
    @property
    def length(self):
        return sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)
    
    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        pass
```

Introducing a no-op setter is necessary as apparently the dataclass-created init method tries to assign to *length* even though there isn't a default value and it explicitly sets `init=False`...

Surely there has to be a better way right?

Comment: I'm wondering if you're just not crossing the thin border between a data class i.e. some thin wrapper around data and a proper class representing an entity *with operations on itself* - in your case a Vector ([Unity3D example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html)).

Comment: I would question if you do want to make this class ordered.  Consider `order=True` implies `eq=True` but you probably don't want consider two vectors to be equal if they are the same length.  Consider that you can still sort items based on `length` with something like `sorted(vectors, key=lambda v: v.length)` and similarly for other uses.  In this case I would keep `length` as a property and not a field.

Comment: The "more readable / less hacky way" is to properly implement `__lt__`, IMO. It becomes much clearer to anyone reading your code exactly *how* two `Vector2D` instances are compared. And this way you won't need the `length` dataclass field and the `length.setter` method anymore, just the `length` property.

Comment: I'm impressed by the fast responses, and I do admit that you raise valid points. Probably shoe horning this into a data class just to make the class definition more concise might not actually improve readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not answer your exact question, but you mentioned that the reason that you didnt want to have length as a property and a not field was because you would have to

> write `__lt__`, et.al by myself

While you do have to implement `__lt__` by yourself, you can actually get away with implementing just that

```py
from functools import total_ordering
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from math import sqrt

@total_ordering
@dataclass
class Vector2D:
    x: int
    y: int

    @property
    def length(self):
        return sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Vector2D):
            return NotImplemented

        return self.length < other.length

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Vector2D):
            return NotImplemented

        return self.length == other.length


print(Vector2D(3, 4) > Vector2D(4, 1))
```

The reason this works is because `total_ordering` just adds all the other equality methods based on `__eq__`  and `__lt__`

Comment: In your example of a possibly incorrect comparison, they do have the same length?

Comment: Yeah thats true, i guess its an implementation detail if `Vector2D(0, 1) == Vector2D(1, 0)`

Comment: This is desired behavior, from OP: "In the example below I define a Vector2D class that should be compared on its length."

Comment: I hadn't considered something like ``total_ordering``. While this does not answer the exact question I asked, it does save me from typing out an abundance of redundant comparison functions and is much more readable than my initial code. I'll go with that approach, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the example you present is a good use case for what you are trying to do. Nevertheless, for completeness sake, here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Vector2D:
    x: int = field(compare=False)
    y: int = field(compare=False)
    length: int = field(default=property(lambda s: sqrt(s.x**2+s.y**2)), init=False)
```

This works because `dataclass` sets defaults as values on the class attributes unless the value is a list, dict or set.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could implement the `@property` and other methods manually, this can make you lose other desirable features like in this case using `hash=False` if you wanted to use your `Vector2D` in a `dict`. Additionally, letting it implement dunder methods for you makes your code less error prone e.g. you can't forget to `return NotImplemented` which is a common mistake.

The drawback is that implementing the correct type-hint is not easy and that there can be some minor caveats, but once the type-hint is implemented it can be easily used anywhere.

The property (descriptor) type-hint:

```py
import sys
from typing import Any, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar, overload

if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    from typing import Type
else:
    from builtins import type as Type

IT = TypeVar("IT", contravariant=True)
CT = TypeVar("CT", covariant=True)
GT = TypeVar("GT", covariant=True)
ST = TypeVar("ST", contravariant=True)


class Property(Protocol[CT, GT, ST]):

    # Get default attribute from a class.
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: Type[Any]) -> CT:
        ...

    # Get attribute from an instance.
    def __get__(self, instance: IT, owner: Optional[Type[IT]] = ...) -> GT:
        ...

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        ...

    def __set__(self, instance: Any, value: ST) -> None:
        ...
```

From here, we can now type-hint our `property` object when using a `dataclass`. Use `field(default=property(...))` if you need to use the other options in `field(...)`.

```py
import sys
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from math import hypot

# Use for read-only property.
if sys.version_info < (3, 11):
    from typing import NoReturn as Never
else:
    from typing import Never


@dataclass(order=True)
class Vector2D:
    x: int = field(compare=False)
    y: int = field(compare=False)

    # Properties return themselves as their default class variable.
    # Read-only properties never allow setting a value.
    
    # If init=True, then it would assign self.length = Vector2D.length for the
    # default factory.
    
    # Setting repr=False for consistency with init=False.
    length: Property[property, float, Never] = field(
        default=property(lambda v: hypot(v.x, v.y)),
        init=False,
        repr=False,
    )


v1 = Vector2D(3, 4)
v2 = Vector2D(6, 8)

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(Vector2D.length)  # builtins.property
    reveal_type(v1.length)        # builtins.float

assert v1.length == 5.0
assert v2.length == 10.0
assert v1 < v2
```

Try it on [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=cbd70906eab06523f7287bc649c3e549).